# SQL 2014 - SSIS or Stored procedures to copy data from SQL Server to SQL Server with same table structure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have an SSIS project to load data from CSV to a staging area on SQL Server (DB_Stage).

> The main purpose of Staging is to prepare the data ready to move to the Production database(DB_Prod) and in the process flag any errors with data or files.

DB_Stage is created by taking create table scripts from DB_Prod, so the table structure in both databases is same. Once the load to DB_Stage is successful then data need to be moved to DB_Prod.

I'm thinking to create a stored procedure for each table in DB_Stage to push data to DB_Prod as there is no transformation required and also thinking SQL to SQL is faster. However I read some articles which say SSIS has the capacity to parallel processing and load will be much faster. But I didn't understand it completely.

I can create another set of SSIS packages to move data from Stage to Prod using Biml with in no time. But I need some advice on which is the best approach. Stored procedures or SSIS packages in my scenario.

One advantage if I use SSIS package is I can configure the destination database, so Stage data can be loaded to any server/database (this is a requirement for us).

If I use stored procedures I don't find a way to parametarize the target database. It seems I must hard code this way...

> insert into Prod_DB.dbo.Table1(col list)
>   select (col list) from DB_Stage.dbo.table1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Best approach is to use existing hardcoded third party tools for schema/data compare and synchronize.

Comment: What is your question?  Be explicit.

Comment: my question: Best approach to copy data from SQL to SQL with same table structure with NO transformation, SSIS or TSQL stored procs. I have 150 tables and data ranging from few hundreds to few million rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you don't have any transformation to use in between dev and prod environment. I would recommend you to use SSIS instead of stored procedure. SSIS will consider this as a synchronous task and will start transferring record as soon as it can. SSIS can take advantage of buffer pipe line which you can control and achieve parallelism.

I would recommend few setting to be done when using SSIS in this case:

- Avoid table locks on destination
- Adjust max. number of rows & max. row commit size
- If you are planning to transfer data for multiple table at once then set max. thread and buffer accordingly.

I am pretty sure you will see performance gain by using SSIS instead of TSQL here.

Comment: Anuj, thanks for the reply. it now makes more sense to me to use SSIS over TSQL. I will have 150 packages one for each table and data ranging from hundreds to few million, so please suggest how do I achieve parallelism or suggest some articles I can go through. Do I need to split the packages into groups and execute each group in parallel.

Comment: @MSBI-Geek I would suggest you to keep 4-6 DFT in each sequence container. Now, depending upon the size of each table, you can keep 1-2 large table in each container. You can have 6-10 packages to cover all 150 tables. I recommend you to keep all properties value as default and then measure the time it takes. You may then want to adjust EngineThreads property of DFT accordingly. Other than this, if your source table has huge amount of data then reduce row commit size on OLEDB destination to avoid your RAM getting filled with data.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, there are 2 ways to copy the data from 1 server to another. Let's go through them one by one.

Stored Procedure:
You will have to first create a linked server connection between the Prod server and the Staging server by using [sp_addlinkedserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190479.aspx). This would allow you to use 4 part naming to reference tables from Staging Server like [ProdServer].[ProdDB].[dbo].[Table1]
Here you can make use of what one calls a '[dynamic query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)'. In this particular kind of query, we can specify certain values of a SQL Query as varchar variables and then execute the query.
What you will be essentially writing is a query as follows:

```
'INSERT INTO [' + @ProdServer + '].[' + @ProdDB +'].[dbo].[Table1] (col list)
SELECT (col list) FROM [DB_Stage].[dbo].[table1]'
```

In here you have the condition of 4,000 characters in case of nvarchar strings, or 8,000 characters in case of varchar strings.

SSIS:
As you have mentioned SSIS allows you to parallelize the data flow from your staging server to Prod Server. The methods are quite straight forward as explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2064/transfer-database-task-and-transfer-sql-server-objects-task-in-ssis/). However, if the table is too large, I would suggest you to use [Balanced Data Distributor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj191628.aspx), which is an optimization on the parallel data flow.

Comment: Hi Subham, thanks for the reply. I thought of using the dynamic query in stored procedures, but I'm little concerned about the execution performance as the query is built each time it is executed. I have 150 tables. I'll look at BDD, thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: Considering the queries are quite simple, I don't think the performance impact would be large. Moreover dynamic queries give you the advantage of a dynamic schema of the table, if that is a requirement to you. SSIS packages can not inherently handle that condition.
Upvote if helpful :)